# Symfony2: using Facebook PHP Api, BaseFacebook class can not be loaded

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, autoload

I think this is related to the autoloading of Symfony2:

I created a

```
class FacebookSessionPersistence extends \BaseFacebook
```

Further, I inserted following line in the autoload.php:

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Facebook'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/facebook/src',));
```

Still I get following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseFacebook' not found in /var/www/..../Bundle/Library/FacebookSessionPersistence.php on line 14

What should I do, to tell Symfony to load this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `class FacebookSessionPersistence extends Facebook\BaseFacebook`

If this fails you'll need to explicitly include base_facebook.php file

You should also take a look at [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle) - it probably solves whatever you're trying to do. At least I know for sure that it has a `fos_facebook.api` service, which is what you're trying to implement..

Comment: FOSFacebookBundle made more troubles than it solved, and after the switch to oAuth2 i never got it running again.

Comment: You solution does not work for me. Still getting a class not found exception.

Comment: I installed FOSFacebookBundle, which provides the autoloading mechanism which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `autoload_classmap.php` file, it should contain something like this

```
'BaseFacebook' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php',
'Facebook' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/facebook.php',
'FacebookApiException' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php',
```

if you installed the `"facebook/php-sdk"` with composer, it should be done automatically.