# FOSFacebookBundle - FacebookSessionPersistence - Fatal error: Class 'BaseFacebook' not found

Tags: facebook, symfony

I'm using [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle) on symfony2. 
I would like to create an object from FacebookSessionPersistence to read facebook User Informations.

But i have the following error:
Fatal error: Class 'BaseFacebook' not found in C:\Users\gp\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\projectOne\p1\vendor\bundles\FOS\FacebookBundle\Facebook\FacebookSessionPersistence.php on line 13

I registered the bundle and the autoloader like in the installation document.
Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: using Facebook PHP Api, BaseFacebook class can not be loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398183/symfony2-using-facebook-php-api-basefacebook-class-can-not-be-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

1.) are you sure you have facebook sdk also installed?

```
[FacebookSDK]
    git=git://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.git
    target=/facebook
```

2.) Are you sure you have config set?

```
  fos_facebook:
      file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
```

Comment: yes,  i installed teh sdk manuall under /vendor/facebook and here is the config.yml fos_facebook:
      file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
      alias:  facebook
      app_id: xxxx
      secret: xxxx
      cookie: true
      permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]

Comment: still, you're missing some key configuration... Are you sure the files are actually physically present? Are you sure you didn't change anything in FacebookSessionPersistence by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `autoload_classmap.php` file, it should contain something like this

```
'BaseFacebook' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php',
'Facebook' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/facebook.php',
'FacebookApiException' => $vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php',
```

if you installed the `"facebook/php-sdk"` with composer, it should be done automatically.